# Prestashop error: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, php-7.4

I developed a custom page within my Prestashop module.
I'm using Prestashop 1.7.7.2 and PHP 7.4.
This is the Controller code:

```php
class MymoduleConfirmemailModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    public $php_self = 'confirmemail';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('confirmemail');
    }
```

This is the code of the template file:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='page_header_container'}{/block}

{block name='page_content'}
    <div>TEST</div>
{/block}
```

When I navigate to corresponding page I receive the following error:
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

And the page doesn't display.
If I remove the line `{extends file='page.tpl'}` it displays as expected "TEST".

Following the stack trace, after some debug I found that the problem is in these lines inside classes/Connection.php:

```php
[...]
$sql = 'SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `id_guest`
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'connections`
        WHERE `id_guest` = ' . (int) $cookie->id_guest . '
        AND `date_add` > \'' . pSQL(date('Y-m-d H:i:00', time() - 1800)) . '\'
        ' . Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_CUSTOMER) . '
        ORDER BY `date_add` DESC';
$result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql, false);
       
---> if (!$result['id_guest'] && (int) $cookie->id_guest) {
[...]
```

The problem is that the query returns false because there is no row containing an id_guest with id `$cookie->id_guest`so the last line throws an error.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you `print_r($result);` after running `$result = Db::getInstance()->getRow($sql, false);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing that PS 1.7.7.2 is not compatible with PHP 7.4 yet :

See

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/

Downgrading to 7.3 should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by testing if the method getCoverWs returns any result set and if not return false. My code was to change to the following on classes/Product.php

```
public function getCoverWs()
{
    $result = $this->getCover($this->id);
    if (!$result) {
        return false;
    }
    return $result['id_image'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $this->getCover($this->id);
//return $result['id_image'];
if(is_array($result)){
   if (array_key_exists('id_image', $result)) {
    return $result['id_image'];
   }
}
return "";
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.